# API call while app not in use / not in background

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm creating an Android application that shares location to the remote server. My app has "Allow all time" location permission. I'm getting location even if the app is killed. how to make the api calls to post the location to the server. even my app is killed?.. like google maps shares the location even if the app is killed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Service class in android

here is a good tutorial for you and how it work(you can find alot of doc in internet too)
[enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/services-in-android-with-example/)

from your broadcast reciever start your service from onReceive method:

```
    @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
         context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Comment: I'm receiving location in a broadcast receiver.. can i start the service from there when the app is killed

Comment: of course you can, check my answer i have edited an out a littel code for launching from broadcast receiver